# Hibernate Search integrated into Play Framework (JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search, hibernate-entitymanager

Im am trying to use Hibernate Search together with Play Framework. It seams very easy and straight forward. But I get a exception (see below):

Here is what I did:

I added dependencies

```
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.8.Final",
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-search-orm" % "5.2.0.Final",
```

I already had Entitymanager and it works fine.

Then I added the Hibernate Search properties:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>models.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                  value="filesystem"/>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase"
                  value="/var/lucene/indexes"/>

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

New about this is only:

```
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                  value="filesystem"/>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase"
                  value="/var/lucene/indexes"/>
```

I added some Annotation to the User:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class User extends Model {

     @Field(index= Index.YES, analyze= Analyze.YES, store= Store.NO)
     public String firstname;
     @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
     public String lastname;
}
```

I start the Server and try to access the site:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.getConfigurationValues()Ljava/util/Map;]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:170) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.4.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.getConfigurationValues()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:404) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
```

Thank you for your Help.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a problem caused by incompatible versions of hibernate-search-orm and hibernate-entitymanager. [It seems like Hibernate Search depends on Hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.*9*.Final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm/5.2.0.Final)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Hibernate Search versions from *5.0.0* to *5.3.0* are compatible with any Hibernate ORM version *4.3.x* (*4.3.0* to latest of the 4.3 series, which currently is *4.3.10*).

But you always must choose the same exact version for *hibernate-entitymanager* and *hibernate-orm*, as these are released together and should not be split & mixed up.

From the stacktrace it seems you were already using Hibernate ORM version *4.3.9* (*hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar*), so you should not use *hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final* but either upgrade EntityManager to *4.3.9* as well, or downgrade hibernate-core to *4.3.8*, or just upgrade both to *4.3.10* (probably the best option).

**Hibernate compatibility rules**

Generally the rule is that hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager need to be at the exact same version; then consult the Hibernate Search documentation to find out for which range it is compatible.

This information can be found in the [README](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/5.2.0.Final/README.md), in the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/), or via the *[pom.xml](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/5.2.0.Final/pom.xml#L149)* (also with the many tools able to interpret Maven metadata).

Compatibility is also mentioned in the downloads page:
 - http://hibernate.org/search/downloads/

The downloads page and the pom file only mention a single, specific Hibernate ORM version (the version it was built with).
The [README](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/5.2.0.Final/README.md) and [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/) specify the range of versions which are meant to be compatible; these are updated by humans though so it might occasionally be less accurate, but if that wouldn't work please file a bug as we do strive to keep compatibility ranges relaxed, especially among minor versions.

The Compatibility definitions and expectations for Hibernate are documented here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Compatibility-Considerations

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to User mhlz in the comments.Seams I had to update the Entity-manager.